# Symfony 3 / CollectionType Field / 'entry_options' => array('label' => ))

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a collection of form embedded in a formType.

```
class RateType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder    ->add('rate')
                    ->add('options', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => RatesHasOptionsType::class,
                'entry_options' => array('label' => __?????_____ ))
                )
                    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'create'));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Rates::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

The embedded form is

```
$builder->add('price', MoneyType::class, array(
    'currency' => 'CHF',
));
```

It comes from a ManytoMany relation : Many Rate can have many option

rates_has_options:

```
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| rate_id   | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| option_id | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| price     | double  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

How can I have the label of my option with the name of the option?
So far it gives me 0, 1, 2, 3 which I believe is the key of the Array of options.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-label ???

Comment: This works for 'choice_label' but looks like it doesn't work for 'label'. Does it?

Answer (score 0):

You should add an `choices` array to `entry_options`. See [this example](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#entry-options):

```
$builder->add('favorite_cities', CollectionType::class, array(
    'entry_type'   => ChoiceType::class,
    'entry_options'  => array(
        'choices'  => array(
            'Nashville' => 'nashville',
            'Paris'     => 'paris',
            'Berlin'    => 'berlin',
            'London'    => 'london',
        ),
    ),
));
```

This will lead to:

```
<select name="favorite_cities">
    <option value="nashville">Nashville</option>
    <option value="paris">Paris</option>
    <option value="berlin">Berlin</option>
    <option value="london">London</option>
</select>
```